Pytorch MemoryMappedTensors causing Bus Error, possibly insufficient memory
I'm loading some data using PyTorch's MemoryMappedTensor (version==2.4.0+cu118) and getting a Bus Error. I'm running the code using WSL2 on Windows 10:

     Operating System: Windows 10 Pro 64-bit (10.0, Build 19045) (19041.vb_release.191206-1406)
             Language: English (Regional Setting: English)
  System Manufacturer: ASUS
                 BIOS: 3603 (type: UEFI)
            Processor: AMD Ryzen 9 5950X 16-Core Processor             (32 CPUs), ~3.4GHz
               Memory: 65536MB RAM
  Available OS Memory: 65436MB RAM
            Page File: 7675MB used, 67487MB available
      DirectX Version: DirectX 12
       Card name: NVIDIA TITAN RTX
    Manufacturer: NVIDIA
       Chip type: NVIDIA TITAN RTX
        DAC type: Integrated RAMDAC
  Display Memory: 56985 MB
Dedicated Memory: 24268 MB
   Shared Memory: 32717 MB


It seems most likely to me that this Bus Error is being caused by insufficient memory; however, I can't understand why this would be an issue when all of my operations are on memory-mapped data, and I have plenty of memory to go around.
Here is the loop in which the error occurs:
    # Populate the empty tensors from .npy files on disk.
    batch = num_output_sensors // 4
    dl = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(disk_dataset, batch_size=batch, num_workers=0)
    i = 0
    pbar = tqdm.tqdm(total=len(disk_dataset))
    for c1, c2, f, kappa, output, sensor_coords in dl:
        _batch = c1.shape[0]
        pbar.update(_batch)
        # 
        # =============
        # PROBLEM CODE:
        # =============
        #
        # data[i : i + _batch] = cls(
        #     f=f,
        #     c1=c1,
        #     c2=c2,
        #     kappa=kappa,
        #     output=output,
        #     sensor_coords=sensor_coords,
        #     batch_size=[_batch]
        # )
        i += _batch

and here it is in context:
@tensorclass
class MemoryMappedTensorDataset:
    # Tensors to be memmapped
    # =======================
    f: torch.Tensor
    kappa: torch.Tensor
    c1: torch.Tensor
    c2: torch.Tensor
    output: torch.Tensor
    sensor_coords: torch.Tensor

    # Dict keys for metadata
    # ======================
    NUM_DATA = "num_data"
    NUM_INPUT_SENSORS_2D = "num_input_sensors_2D"
    NUM_OUTPUT_SENSORS_1D = "num_output_sensors"
    NO_VELOCITY = "no_velocity"
    ALL_KEYWORDS = [NUM_DATA, NUM_INPUT_SENSORS_2D, NUM_OUTPUT_SENSORS_1D, NO_VELOCITY]

    @classmethod
    def from_data_directory(cls, data_dir:Path):

        ( num_data,
          num_input_sensors_2D,
          num_input_sensors_total,
          num_output_sensors,
          no_velocity ) = cls._extract_meta_data(data_dir)
        
        # Fix shape of data tensors
        # NOTE: If there is no velocity, c1 and c2 are identically zero;
        #       however, the current implementation still passes these 
        #       variables. So for now, I'll include them as a constant,
        #       stored once per data point
        # NOTE: output_shape includes data for u, du/dx, and du/dy
        input_shape_constant = (num_data, 1)
        input_shape_2D = (num_data, *num_input_sensors_2D)
        input_shape_flattened = (num_data, num_input_sensors_total, 1)
        output_shape = (num_data, 3)
        coord_shape = (num_data, 2)
        c_shape = input_shape_constant if no_velocity else input_shape_2D

        # Creates empty memmapped tensors
        data = cls(
            f = MemoryMappedTensor.empty(input_shape_flattened, dtype=torch.float),
            kappa = MemoryMappedTensor.empty(input_shape_2D, dtype=torch.float),
            c1 = MemoryMappedTensor.empty(c_shape, dtype=torch.float),
            c2 = MemoryMappedTensor.empty(c_shape, dtype=torch.float),
            output = MemoryMappedTensor.empty(output_shape, dtype=torch.float),
            sensor_coords = MemoryMappedTensor.empty(coord_shape, dtype=torch.float),
            batch_size=[num_data]
        )

        # Locks the tensorclass and ensures that is_memmap() will return True.
        data.memmap_()

        # Collect data from disk
        disk_dataset = cls._extract_data(data_dir)

        # Populate the empty tensors from .npy files on disk.
        batch = num_output_sensors // 4
        dl = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(disk_dataset, batch_size=batch, num_workers=0)
        i = 0
        pbar = tqdm.tqdm(total=len(disk_dataset))
        for c1, c2, f, kappa, output, sensor_coords in dl:
            _batch = c1.shape[0]
            pbar.update(_batch)
            # 
            # =============
            # PROBLEM CODE:
            # =============
            #
            # data[i : i + _batch] = cls(
            #     f=f,
            #     c1=c1,
            #     c2=c2,
            #     kappa=kappa,
            #     output=output,
            #     sensor_coords=sensor_coords,
            #     batch_size=[_batch]
            # )
            i += _batch

        return disk_dataset


    @classmethod
    def _extract_data(cls, data_dir:Path):

        npy_dir = data_dir / "npy_data"

        if not npy_dir.exists():
            raise RuntimeError(
                "No numpy data directory found for the dataset at %s. "
                "Aborting!" % npy_dir.as_posix()
            )

        for filename in ["c1", "c2", "f", "kappa", "output"]:
            data_path = npy_dir / ("%s.npy" % filename)
            if not data_path.exists():
                raise RuntimeError(
                    "No numpy data file found at %s. "
                    "Aborting!" % data_path.as_posix()
                )

        c1 = torch.from_numpy(np.load(npy_dir / "c1.npy", mmap_mode="r+"))
        c2 = torch.from_numpy(np.load(npy_dir / "c2.npy", mmap_mode="r+"))
        f = torch.from_numpy(np.load(npy_dir / "f.npy", mmap_mode="r+"))
        kappa = torch.from_numpy(np.load(npy_dir / "kappa.npy", mmap_mode="r+"))
        output = torch.from_numpy(np.load(npy_dir / "output.npy", mmap_mode="r+"))
        sensor_coords = torch.from_numpy(np.load(npy_dir / "sensor_coords.npy", mmap_mode="r+"))

        return torch.utils.data.TensorDataset(
            c1,
            c2,
            f,
            kappa,
            output,
            sensor_coords
        )


    @classmethod
    def _extract_meta_data(cls, data_dir:Path):

        meta_data_file_path = data_dir / "meta.yaml"

        if not meta_data_file_path.exists():
            raise RuntimeError(
                "No metadata found for the dataset at %s. "
                "Aborting!" % meta_data_file_path.as_posix()
            )
        
        meta_data:dict
        with meta_data_file_path.open(mode="r") as yml_file:
            meta_data = yaml.safe_load(yml_file)

        try:
            num_data = meta_data[cls.NUM_DATA]
            num_input_sensors_2D = meta_data[cls.NUM_INPUT_SENSORS_2D]
            num_output_sensors_1D = meta_data[cls.NUM_OUTPUT_SENSORS_1D]
            no_velocity = meta_data[cls.NO_VELOCITY]
        except KeyError:
            tabbed_keywords = "\n\t-".join(['']+cls.ALL_KEYWORDS)
            raise RuntimeError(
                f"One or more of the required metadata are missing from {(data_dir / 'metadata.yaml').as_posix()}:"
                f"{tabbed_keywords}\nAborting!"
            )
        
        try:
            num_input_sensors_total = num_input_sensors_2D[0] * num_input_sensors_2D[1]
        except IndexError:
            raise RuntimeError(
                f"Expected {cls.NUM_INPUT_SENSORS_2D} to be a tuple in {(data_dir / 'metadata.yaml').as_posix()}, "
                f"but got {str(num_input_sensors_2D)} instead. \nAborting!"
            )

        return num_data, num_input_sensors_2D, num_input_sensors_total, num_output_sensors_1D, no_velocity

The bus error only occurs if I uncomment the "PROBLEM CODE" that I've called out above, and it always occurs at 80% of completion. If it is caused by insufficient memory, I'm at a loss as to why:

Shouldn't the memory use be fairly constant between iterations? Why would it increase?
And for that matter, the memory required to store an individual batch should not be especially large; is there a reason the memory use might be larger than expected?
Is it possible the Bus Error is being caused, not by insufficient memory, but insufficient virtual disk space on WSL2? If so, why wouldn't that happen when I first instantiate the MemoryMappedTensors?
Is there another obvious possibility that I'm overlooking?

